# How to compile glib on android

Tags: android, glib

Does anyone have a set of .mk files (and anything else needed) to compile glib on android? The NEWS file implies that at least version 2.41.5 is supported (there is a commit message about not using issetugid() on android.)

I have successfully compiled https://github.com/ieei/glib but this is only 2.26 and I thought I'd check before re-inventing the wheel.

Thanks,

Comment: The Android support is built into the configure script.  If that's not sufficient to answer your question you should ask somewhere the glib developers actually hang out (one of their mailing lists, their IRC channel, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this work using the standalone tool chain and the following setup:

```
git clone https://git.gnome.org/browse/glib
cd glib
NOCONFIGURE=1 ./autogen.sh

cat << EOF > android.cache
glib_cv_stack_grows=no
glib_cv_uscore=no
ac_cv_func_posix_getpwuid_r=no
ac_cv_func_posix_getgrgid_r=no
EOF

CPPFLAGS=/path/to/standalone/include LDFLAGS=/path/to/standalone/lib ./configure \
--prefix=/path/to/standalone --bindir=$AS_BIN --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=arm-linux-androideabi \
--cache-file=android.cache
```

Comment: what is autogen.sh?